# Insert avarage value from Table one into Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to accomplish something like this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET totalPayed = AVG(p.paymentMade)
FROM Payments p
WHERE Users.username = p.username;
```

Error message:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
```

How can I solve this without using AVG in the SET line?

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? mysql, oracel, mssql?

Comment: Sorry for missing it out: mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing an `avg` in subquery and joining it to the main table using `username` and then update the `totalpayed`.

```
UPDATE U
  SET totalPayed=p.avg_payment
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT username,AVG(p.paymentMade) avg_payment
  FROM Payments 
  GROUP BY username ) P ON U.username =p.username
```

Comment: Great, that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this be using a sub query. Like this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET totalPayed = 
(
    SELECT AVG(p.paymentMade) 
    FROM Payments p
    WHERE Users.username = p.username;
)
```

The thing is that if you are using a `JOIN` then for the users that do not have payment you will not set the value